# Dividing Histograms in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am reading in a csv file through pandas, and making simple histograms as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],header=0)
hFare = df['Fare'].dropna().hist(bins=[0,10,20,30,45,60,75,100,600],label = "All")
hSurFare = df[df.Survived==1]['Fare'].dropna().hist(bins=[0,10,20,30,45,60,75,100,600],label="Survivors")
```

What I would like is to have a bin by bin ratio of the two histograms.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we'll create some example data. In future if you're asking a question about pandas it's best to include example data that people can easily copy-paste into their Python console:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fare': np.random.uniform(0, 600, 400), 
                   'Survived': np.random.randint(0, 2, 400)})
```

Then use `pd.cut` to bin the data in the same way as you were doing in your histogram:

```
df['fare_bin'] = pd.cut(df['Fare'], bins=[0,10,20,30,45,60,75,100,600])
```

Look at the total count and survived count within each bin (you could probably do this
as separate columns, but I'm just doing it quickly):

```
df.groupby('fare_bin').apply(lambda g: (g.shape[0], g.loc[g['Survived'] == 1, :].shape[0]))

Out[34]: 
fare_bin
(0, 10]           (7, 4)
(10, 20]          (9, 6)
(100, 600]    (326, 156)
(20, 30]          (5, 4)
(30, 45]         (12, 6)
(45, 60]        (15, 11)
(60, 75]         (13, 7)
(75, 100]        (13, 6)
dtype: object
```

Then write a quick function to get the ratio:

```
def get_ratio(g):
    try:
        return float(g.shape[0]) / g.loc[g['Survived'] == 1, :].shape[0]
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return np.nan
df.groupby('fare_bin').apply(get_ratio)

Out[30]: 
fare_bin
(0, 10]       1.750000
(10, 20]      1.500000
(100, 600]    2.089744
(20, 30]      1.250000
(30, 45]      2.000000
(45, 60]      1.363636
(60, 75]      1.857143
(75, 100]     2.166667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Marius, thanks so much, this works great.  I will be sure to include data links in the future.

Comment: @j.a.gartner: No worries. It's better to try to create example data that people can copy-paste easily into their python console than link to a file on an external site. You can either do what I did, i.e. use numpy's random number generators to put together something that looks vaguely like your real data, or maybe just print the first 20 rows of your data and include that in your question, since pandas has a `read_clipboard()` function that makes it pretty to import it.